# "IOException: There is not enough space on the disk." while there is enough space

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, save

I made sequence of operations (on local disk):

1. Copy file to ###.bak
2. Save file to ###
3. Delete file ###.bak

Code:

```
File.Copy(filename, filename + ".bak");
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Close();
File.Delete(filename + ".bak");
```

During deleting I got exception:

```
IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
```

Size of both files is maximum few MB. And I checked - there is enough free space on disk (more than few GBs). 
What are possible reasons for that situations?

It's a desktop app (WPF), running on OS drive, on admin account.

Comment: Could you show us some code, please? Wich method do you use to delete the files? `System.IO.File.Delete`?

Comment: Code is posted. Yes, I used `System.IO.File.Delete`

Comment: I suggest you to check a permission exception.

Comment: Try to narrow on the problem: (1) make 200% sure you get your file sizes and free disk space right. (2) make 200% sure you're `filename` is the file you think it is. (3) try your code with really small files (e.g. <1KB in size) and see if the error still happens (4) try to copy the file manually using explorer or cmd.exe/copy and see if the error still happens.

Comment: I think you are not getting the error on File.Delete, cause File.Delete calls internally Win32Native.DeleteFile. This exception is raised on File.Copy, cause this method calls File.InternalCopy as listed in your StackTrace

Comment: Generally the code works well on 10+ machines. The error occurred only once and we can't reproduce it. ad 1, 2, 4 - we checked it, there weren't any problems. @up I suspect the same, but it still doesn't make situation clearer.

Comment: Well, if you seen it once, and cannot reproduce it, it might have indeed been a temporary problem. I.e. at the moment the code ran there was indeed not enough space free, when you looked _afterwards_ (even if just a couple of seconds) there was again enough space. Another application or the OS itself could have had some (unexpected or not) space in use at that time.

Comment: I had free more than 10GB at that moment! It's not critical part of app, so I can catch that exception, but for me it's not graceful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making this operation on an hard drive different from the OS one?
Maybe you have lot of space in drive D, but when deleting the file you're actually moving it in the recycle-bin, that is in C drive.
Try to check this...

Comment: Isn't there a separate "Recycle Bin" folder ("RECYCLER" root directory) per drive? I though so. But regardless, `File.Delete` does not use the Recycle Bin at all.

Comment: I thought it uses the recycle bin because of the strack trace he printed out... third line `at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)` makes me think about copying file to recycle bin...

Comment: Well, that _could_ be the case, but I doubt it. Because even if the RecycleBin stuff does a copy somewhere internally and _would_ be used by `File.Delete`, it is unlikely it is done inside .NET, but would be in bowels of the OS/shell. Also, that the stack is the result of the actual `File.Copy` seems much more likely to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using disk quotas? If yes, maybe on the server that it failed on, that account was using a lot of disk at that time.